# Delete all but one column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to drop all columns save the index and a column named 'bob'

How would I do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
df = df[['bob']]
```

*and the other columns will be garbage collected.*

Answer (score 6):

you can use df.loc accessor

```
df=df.loc[:,['bob']]
```